# Checking inner exceptions in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, inner-exception

Probably an obvious question from a programming novice:

I'm debugging a Silverlight project in Visual Studio 2010. How/where do I check the "inner exception"? Is this something I select under "Debug"?

UPDATE:
I'm trying to figure out why I started receiving the following error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application
```

Code: 4004
Category: ManagedRuntimeError
Message: System.Exception: Submit error is not handled!
   at Telerik.Windows.Data.QueryableDomainServiceCollectionView`1.OnDomainContextSubmittCompleted(SubmitOperation submitOperation)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.SubmitOperation.InvokeCompleteAction()
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.OperationBase.Complete(Exception error)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.SubmitOperation.Complete(OperationErrorStatus errorStatus)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.<>c_*DisplayClassb.b*_3(Object )

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to Enable [First Chance Exceptions](http://florianreischl.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-enable-first-chance-exceptions.html)? You can go to Debug > Exceptions > Common Language Runtime Exceptions and check the 'Thrown' check box. Hopefully this will help you break right at the source of the Inner Exception.

Answer (score 0):

It's within your exception object.  `InnerException`.  If you're programmatically handling the error, you could capture it via your try/catch. e.g.

```
try
{
   // Do something.
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
}
```

If you're simply trying to see it within the editor, when the exception is thrown click `View Detail' and expand the exception to see the InnerException

Comment: See update above for error message. Tried added the Console.WriteLine and still getting the same thing as before - a popup with Microsoft Script Editor with the above error message.